# setting objects equal to eachother (java)

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, equals

So I have a class called Person which looks like this

```
public class Person {

    private String personName;


    public String toString(){
        return personName;
    }

    public Person(String personName){
        this.personName = personName;
    }

}
```

and another class in which I am creating the object(s) person

```
public class IdanJavaTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Bob");
        System.out.println("p1 : " + p1);

        Person p2 = new Person("Joe");
        System.out.println("p2 :" + p2);

    }

}
```

so far everything is fine and my print statement is
p1: Bob
p2: Joe

Now I want to create a new object, p3 and set it equal to p1
my class now looks like this:

```
public class IdanJavaTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person("Bob");
        System.out.println("p1 : " + p1);

        Person p2 = new Person("Joe");
        System.out.println("p2 :" + p2);

        Person p3 = new Person (p1);
        System.out.println("p3 equal to p1:" + p3.equals(p1));

    }

}
```

when I try to do this I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor Person(Person) is undefined

    at vehicleassignment.IdanJavaTask.main(IdanJavaTask.java:13)
```

I am thinking I will need to add a method to my main (Person) class, but I do not know why or what to add? why can't I just set the objects equal to eachother?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret "set the objects equal to each other".

One is that you want `p1` and `p3` to refer to *the same* object. Like how Clark Kent and Superman are two names (references) for the same person. This would be accomplished by:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Jim");
Person p3 = p1;
```

In this scenario, if anything happens to `p1`, that same thing has happened to `p3`. If you kill Clark Kent, you have killed Superman (as they are one and the same). Java determines equality with the `equals(Object o)` method - two objects `a` and `b` are equal iff `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` return `true`. These two objects will be equal using the base `Object` definition of equality, so you don't have to worry about that.

The other way to interpret your meaning is to create a *new* person object, which happens to be an exact copy of the first person. In order to do this, you'd have to add another constructor to your person class that takes a person as an argument:

```
public class Person {

    private String personName;

    public String toString(){
        return personName;
    }

    public Person(String personName){
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public Person(Person personToCopy){
        this.personName = personToCopy.personName;
    }

}
```

With this setup, you can do what you're doing in your main.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Bob");
Person p3 = new Person(p1); //Will have name Bob.
```

In order to make `p1` and `p3` equal, we have to teach the Person class to use its fields for checking equality. We can do this by overriding the `equals` method in class person.

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(! (o instanceof Person)) return false; //a Person can't be equal to a non-person

    Person p = (Person) o;
    return personName == null && p.personName == null || personName.equals(p.personName);
}
```

Whenever we overwrite the `equals` method, it is good practice to also overwrite the `hashcode` method, which returns a unique `int` for each Object. Since the only field that a `Person` object has is its name, we can simply use that hashcode.

```
public int hashCode(){
    return personName == null ? 0 : personName.hashCode();
}
```

So all together, our Person class looks like this:

```
public class Person {

    private String personName;

    public String toString(){
        return personName;
    }

    public Person(String personName){
        this.personName = personName;
    }

    public Person(Person personToCopy){
        this.personName = personToCopy.personName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(! (o instanceof Person)) return false; //a Person can't be equal to a non-person

        Person p = (Person) o;
        return personName == null && p.personName == null || personName.equals(p.personName);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return personName == null ? 0 : personName.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first example, what if I change p1? Will p3 also change?

Answer (score 3):

```
Person p3 = new Person(p1);
```

This is known as a *copy constructor*. You'll need to define it explicitly, in this case:

```
public Person(Person p) {
    this.personName = p.personName;
}
```

You also need to override the `equals()` method (and the `hashCode()` method) in order to use it, otherwise the `equals()` method of the root class `Object` would be used, which always returns false:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (personName == null) {
        if (other.personName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!personName.equals(other.personName))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

See [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

No object in Java has a default copy constructor, with the exception of autoboxed objects like `Float` or `Integer` which are indeed copied.

This means that under all circumstances it's your duty to define a copy constructor and specify what is copied, in your example:

```
public Person(Person other) {
  this.personName = other.personName;
}
```

Since in Java everything is passed by reference a plain assignment would just make 2 variables point to the same instance, eg:

```
Person p1 = new Person("Joe");
Person p2 = p1;
// now both point to the same object, not intended behavior in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want p3 to reference p2, meaning a change to p2 will update p3 and vice versa, just do

```
Person p3 = p2;
```

if you want to clone the data and have two distinct, but 'equal' copies of the person, you can implement a constructor in Person that takes a Person and copies the values into the classes fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your Person class constructor. You defined it to accept String type only and you gave it an object "p1" when you instantiate it. Editing the constructor or creating a new one will solve it.