# Error when trying to set objects equal to one and other (java, beginner)

Tags: java

I want to set objects equal to one and other,  but when i do so i receive the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>   Duplicate local variable current
>   Duplicate local variable h1 at objectx3Problem.mainmethod.main(mainmethod.java:15)"

Here is my source code:

```
public class mainmethod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    human h1        = new human();
    human h2        = new human();
    human current   = new human();

    System.out.println(h1.getHealth());

    human current = h1; // error here
    current.DecreaseHealth();
    human h1 = current; //error here
    System.out.println("h1 has " + h1.getHealth() + "health");


    }

}
```

and

```
public class human {

    private int Health = 100;
    public int getHealth(){return Health;}
    public void setHealth(int Health){this.Health = Health;}

    public void DecreaseHealth()
    {
        Health = Health - 5;

    }

}
```

I have read the same question here [setting objects equal to eachother (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855198/setting-objects-equal-to-eachother-java),

but I do not understand how the top answer and my approach are different.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying to re-declare a variable that already exists.  Did you mean to just use the existing one?  `current = h1;` ?  Or did you mean to create a new variable?  In which case you'd want to give it a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward:

You defined a variable here:

```
human current   = new human();
```

Then you try to create the same variable here:

```
human current = h1; // error here
```

The correct way is not use the type:

```
current = h1;
```

Same for the other variable.

Note make sure to read and properly use [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: UPDATE: at the risk of depriving the community of your assistance, I will not delete this question. Thanks for the tip about naming conventions, that was also helpful to me.